Subset based on a reference value of a variable and identical dates
suppose to have the following:
data DB;
  input ID :$20.Date :date9. Code :$20.;
  format Date date9.;
cards;
0001 07JUL2014   PNE
0001 07JUL2014   CARD
0001 04MAY2016   ANEST
0002 19MAR2014   CARD
0002 22MAR2014   OCU
0003 27JUN2022   ALT
0004 18OCT2015   OCU
0004 18OCT2015   DER
0004 18OCT2015   PNE
0005 10AUG2019   PNE
;


Is there a way to subset DB based on the following rule, i.e., all the IDs where "PNE" occurs in the same day with another Code (different from PNE of course) to get the following?
data DB1;
  input ID :$20.Date :date9. Code :$20.;
  format Date date9.;
cards;
0001 07JUL2014   PNE
0001 07JUL2014   CARD
0004 18OCT2015   OCU
0004 18OCT2015   DER
0004 18OCT2015   PNE
;

Thank you in advance

In a DATA step, you can do this with a double-DoW loop:
data want ;
  do until (last.Date) ;
    set db ;
    by ID Date ;
    if Code='PNE' then _foundPNE=1 ;
    if Code ne 'PNE' then _foundOther=1 ;
  end ;
  do until (last.Date) ;
    set db ;
    by ID Date ;
    if _foundPNE and _foundOther then output ;
  end ;
  drop _: ;
run ;

It essentially reads the data in ID-Date by-groups.  You read the records in the by-group once to flag whether there is a PNE code or another code in the by group. Then you read the records in the by-group again to conditionally output the desired by-groups.

A simple SQL may be what you want.
proc sql ;
  create table want as
  select * from have
  group id, date
  having count(*) > 1 and range(code='PNE') = 1
  ;

Edit per Quentin's astuteness

Maybe having count(*) > 1 and range(code='PNE')=1 instead?  I assume if there was an ID-DATE with two records that are about code='PNE', the OP would not want that record selected.

You can use SQL like the following:
proc sql;
  create table DB1 as
    select
      DB.*
    from
      DB
    inner join
    (select distinct
       lhs.ID,
       lhs.Date
     from
       DB as lhs
     inner join
       DB as rhs
     on
      lhs.ID   eq rhs.ID
    and
      lhs.Date eq rhs.Date
    where
      lhs.Code eq "PNE"
    and
      rhs.Code ne "PNE"
    ) as subquery
   on
     DB.ID eq subquery.ID
   and
     DB.Date eq subquery.Date
   order by
     DB.ID,
     DB.Date
  ;
quit;


I would give a try to this query:
proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
        select      distinct
                    db.*

        from        db
        
        join        db as db2
        on          db2.id = db.id
            and     db2.date = db.date
            and     db2.code = 'PNE'

        group by    dn.id, db.date
        having      count(*) > 1
    ;
quit;

There is no indication if the ID must be the same or not, I assume that's the case. If not, you can just remove the db2.id = db.id in the join clause.

ID 005 does not match the logic: "all the IDs where 'PNE' occurs in the same day with another Code (different from PNE of course)".  ID 005 only has one record.

If ID005 must not output, then it must be clearly specified.
The author wrote "all the IDs where "PNE" occurs" which for me of course includes PNE itself.
Strange how people consider things obvious or not. That's the reason why specification is really important, and in this case we're in this situation.
That does not mean the programming is erroneous and deserves a blame...

I'm confused.  There was a second part to that sentence: "where 'PNE' occurs in the same day with another Code (different from PNE of course)" I think your solution ignores the 'same day with another Code' part.

Oh, thank you for highlighting this, you're totally right.
